Determining the Signature of a Metric Tensor Given a Set of $g-$null Vectors
I am currently working through the following worksheet on metric manifolds and am having trouble understanding the solution for part of the following question:

Let $g$ be a symmetric $(0,2)-$tensor over some vector space. State
the possible signatures for the following set of $g$-null vectors:
I. A cone through the origin,
II. A point in the origin,
III. A straight line through the origin, and
IV. A plane through the origin

Here is what I have figured out and where I am confused:
First, recall that a $g$-null vector is a vector $X \in T_{p}M$ such that $g(X,X)=0$. Now, for our purposes lets assume the vector space in question is $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Therefore, we can construct the following solutions knowing that we can write $g(X,X) = X^{i}X^{j}g_{ij} = 0$ with respect to a choice of basis:
I. $g(X,X) = (X^{1})^{2}+(X^{2})^{2}-(X^{3})^{2}=0$ since we know the equation of a cone in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Therefore, our possible choice of signatures are $(++-)$ and $(--+)$, by simply multiplying each side by $-1.$
II. $g(X,X) = (X^{1})^{2}+(X^{2})^{2}+(X^{3})^{2}=0$ only has one solution, which is $0$, therefore our possible signatures are $(+++)$ and $(---)$.
IV. To obtain a plane through the origin, we can choose $g_{11}=g_{22}=0$ such that $g(X,X)=(X^{3})^{2}=0$, so our signatures are $(00+)$ and $(00-)$.
Where I am stuck is the third case: a straight line through the origin. I watched the video solution and the lecturer says to set any component $g_{ij}$ to zero and just consider the other non-zero components as $g(X,X)=(X^{2})^{2}+(X^{3})^{2}=0$. But the only solution to this is $0$ so I'm not understanding how this yields a set of $g-$null vectors that constitutes a line through the origin, regardless of which components of $g$ you choose to be $0$?
Any insight is appreciated, thank you for your time.

Yes, so the family of null vectors is parametrized by a single vector $X=(X_1,0,0)$

in the line case the allowed signatures are $(0,+,+)$ and $(0,-,-)$

@user8268 - I see that in the solution, but I want to understand why those are the allowed signatures?  Why is it that $g(X,X)=(X^{2})^{2}+(X^{3})^{2}=0$ constitutes a line through the origin (and similarly for the $(0--)$ signature)?

@TaylorRendon: For the $g$ in your previous comment, $g(X, X) = 0$ if and only if $X^2 = 0$ and $X^3 = 0$, so $X = (X^1, X^2, X^3)$ is a null vector if and only if $X = (X^1, 0, 0)$. Therefore, the set of null vectors is $\operatorname{span}{(1, 0, 0)}$, i.e. the $x$-axis.
